# Python Lambda Confusion

Tags: python, lambda

```
def printName(name):
    print(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lambdaList = []
    for i in range(4):
        lambdaList.append(lambda : printName(i))
        lambdaList[0]()
```

I have just learned lambda function. In this case I would like to define different lambda functions like above. However, the result of this script is:

```
0
1
2
3
```

I'm a little bit confused about this result. Why is the first lambda function  changed when I append new elements to this list.
I wish someone can help me.

Comment: The one above isn't a lambda function at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `i` in the lambda is the same `i` in memory as the one being updated by the `for` loop.